# Array size error, c++ visual studio

Tags: c++

My problem is related to stack size I guess,so I am using c++ on visual studio

I have class called `Tag`

This is the header    "Tag.h"

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Tag
{
public:
    Tag();
    ~Tag();
    void setID(string);
    void setMute(bool);
    void setSlotTime(int);
    void setPointer(int);
    void setGroupNo(int);
    void setSlot(int);
    void setParticipate(bool);

    string getID();
    bool getMuted();
    int getSlot();
    int getSlotTime();
    int getPointer();
    int getGroupNo();
    int getParticipate();


private:
    string ID;
    int slot;
    int slotTime;
    bool muted;
    int groupNo;
    int pointer;
    bool participate;

};
```

and I have a `struct`

```
struct Analysis {
    int cnt = 0;
    Tag tag;
    int tagIndex = 0;
};
```

The problem is here with the array size

```
Analysis slotsChecker[256][256];
```

this array definition causing an error unless I reduce the array size. 
I tried to set the stack size to 4194304 but it didn't work

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Avoid naked arrays. Use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead

Comment: From short inspection, taking into account padding and aligment, it seems that you will need at least 4718592 bytes, not counting other stuff on stack. Anyway, you shouldn't have such large arrays on stack.

Answer (score -1):

When stack size is a limitation, you must resort to dynamic memory allocation. The most recommended option is to use `std::vector`, which will handle the memory for you. In the simplest form, would be something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Analysis>> slotsChecker;
slotsChecker.resize(256);
for(auto &s : slotsChecker)
    s.resize(256);
```

Comment: A loop is not needed:  `std::vector<std::vector<Analysis>> slotsChecker(256, std::vector<Analysis>(256));`

Comment: That is completely true. However, wouldn't that allocate memory for 256 Analysis structs more than the loop version? The std::vector you provide in the constructor is itself allocating memory, even though it will be destructed right away.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that does 256 copy-constructors of 256-size vector. Hardly a good thing.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `auto &s`, not `auto s`? Otherwise, it doesn't resize anything!

Comment: @SHADOW.NET, could you show what error it gives exactly? It's hard to help without seeing the error.

Comment: @technik  thank you for your help, problem solved big thumb for you guys